# color picker in android with dynamic colors (xml)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, radio-button, drawable

I need to create a color picker for my product in the app. I know that it possible with radio buttons and drawables, but the problem is that I don't know how to set a dynamic color. I receive data for my product with variety of colors of it. I tried to set drawable with circular shape on it, but when I change the color - circular shape dissappears and gains default rectangle shape with color I set. Also checked item should be noted.

Example:

https://sun9-84.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/byL5MV3SPfLFESg0b9pOIMF7s9xIGcmYqg-fZaHyDz8g3Nj6SGQnQmE4AGIXbqzUOvUcu-qwgIdP7jWHR2CDS6uQ.jpg?size=224x112&quality=96&type=album

Data:

https://sun9-12.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/b0CG4d649km9ePhEiwxyZeD3IYH6qPceZWoCW7mfeunXp5_8R_WDQNPetuYeR7qYhBoozuKTy4Y0IgPnHIoEnr2g.jpg?size=215x126&quality=96&type=album

Comment: myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#your color code")); if will also possible to add custom color

Comment: You haven't posted any code so we have no idea what you're doing, but if you're using a vector drawable, you need to either use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList) or, if you have access to the ``Drawable``, you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat#setTint(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,int)